# Populate dropdown with text value via get elements by class

Tags: javascript

I have a simple dropdown selection field using html and js. Currently all the items in the dropdown list are static 's. Elsewhere I have a table that is user-editable. I'm trying to get the text values of all the cells with a certain class to be in the drop-down.

Here is what I have so far:

```
 <input type="text" placeholder="Account" id="new_account" onkeyup="filterFunction()" onclick="myFunction()">
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a id="accselect1" onclick="selectAccount">About</a>
    <a id="accselect2" onclick="selectAccount">Blogg</a>
    <a id="accselect3" onclick="selectAccount">Blog</a>
    <a id="accselect4" onclick="selectAccount">Contact</a>
    <a id="accselect5" onclick="selectAccount">Custom</a>
    <a id="accselect6" onclick="selectAccount">Support</a>
    <a id="accselect7" onclick="selectAccount">Tools</a>
  </div>
```

```
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

function filterFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("new_account");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
  a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    txtValue = a[i].textContent || a[i].innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      a[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      a[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

Elsewhere on my page I have:

```
<div class="content" id="acc_list"><table class="acc_table" id="acc_table1">
         <tr id=acc_row1acc_table1><td id="acc_name1" class="accname">Cash</td><td id="acc_balance1" class="accbal">$5322.54</td><td class=edtbutton><button class="edit_account" data-modal-target="#modal" id="editaccounts" onclick="sayedit()">✎</button></td></tr>
         <tr id=acc_row2acc_table1><td id="acc_name2" class="accname">Credit Card</td><td id=acc_balance2 class="accbal">$1362.21</td><td class=edtbutton><button class="edit_account" data-modal-target="#modal" id="editaccounts" onclick="sayedit()">✎</button></td></tr>
         <tr id=acc_row3acc_table1><td id="acc_name3" class="accname">Checking Account</td><td id=acc_balance3 class="accbal">$4322.50</td><td class=edtbutton><button class="edit_account" data-modal-target="#modal" id="editaccounts" onclick="sayedit()">✎</button></td></tr>
         <tr id=acc_row4acc_table1><td id="acc_name4" class="accname">Savings Account</td><td id=acc_balance4 class="accbal">$12322.50</td><td class=edtbutton><button class="edit_account" data-modal-target="#modal" id="editaccounts" onclick="sayedit()">✎</button></td></tr>
    </table><div><h4 id="acc">&nbsp<button data-modal-target="#modal" class="add_account" id="editaccounts" onclick="sayadd(); accounttablenum('acc_table1')">+</button></h4></div></div>
```

I'm trying to get the text of all td's with the class .accname to populate the drop-down list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.querySelectorAll(".accname").forEach(element=>{
//get all elements with class .accname and for each of them:

    let dropdown=document.querySelector("#myDropdown");
//get drop-down element

    let options=document.querySelectorAll("#myDropdown > a").length;
//get number of current options

   dropdown.innerHTML =  dropdown.innerHTML + '<a id="accselect'+(options+1)+'" onclick="selectAccount"> '+element.innerText+' </a>'
// append new option with current id +1 and elements inner text
});
```

wrap it all in `function options (){...}`
then call in page load : `options()`

Keep in mind you will have call it probably in `sayadd()` function as well, but you haven't shown full code...

**Working example:**

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

function filterFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("new_account");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
  a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    txtValue = a[i].textContent || a[i].innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      a[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      a[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}

function options() {
  document.querySelectorAll(".accname").forEach(element => {
    let dropdown = document.querySelector("#myDropdown");
    let options = document.querySelectorAll("#myDropdown > a").length;
    dropdown.innerHTML = dropdown.innerHTML + '<a id="accselect' + (options + 1) + '" onclick="selectAccount"> ' + element.innerText + ' </a>'
  });
}
options()
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Account" id="new_account" onkeyup="filterFunction()" onclick="myFunction()">
<div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
  <a id="accselect1" onclick="selectAccount">About</a>
  <a id="accselect2" onclick="selectAccount">Blogg</a>
  <a id="accselect3" onclick="selectAccount">Blog</a>
  <a id="accselect4" onclick="selectAccount">Contact</a>
  <a id="accselect5" onclick="selectAccount">Custom</a>
  <a id="accselect6" onclick="selectAccount">Support</a>
  <a id="accselect7" onclick="selectAccount">Tools</a>
</div>
<div class="content" id="acc_list">
  <table class="acc_table" id="acc_table1">
    <tr id=acc_row1acc_table1>
      <td id="acc_name1" class="accname">Cash</td>
      <td id="acc_balance1" class="accbal">$5322.54</td>
      <td class=edtbutton><button class="edit_account" data-modal-target="#modal" id="editaccounts" onclick="sayedit()">✎</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id=acc_row2acc_table1>
      <td id="acc_name2" class="accname">Credit Card</td>
      <td id=acc_balance2 class="accbal">$1362.21</td>
      <td class=edtbutton><button class="edit_account" data-modal-target="#modal" id="editaccounts" onclick="sayedit()">✎</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id=acc_row3acc_table1>
      <td id="acc_name3" class="accname">Checking Account</td>
      <td id=acc_balance3 class="accbal">$4322.50</td>
      <td class=edtbutton><button class="edit_account" data-modal-target="#modal" id="editaccounts" onclick="sayedit()">✎</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id=acc_row4acc_table1>
      <td id="acc_name4" class="accname">Savings Account</td>
      <td id=acc_balance4 class="accbal">$12322.50</td>
      <td class=edtbutton><button class="edit_account" data-modal-target="#modal" id="editaccounts" onclick="sayedit()">✎</button></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div>
    <h4 id="acc">&nbsp<button data-modal-target="#modal" class="add_account" id="editaccounts" onclick="sayadd(); accounttablenum('acc_table1')">+</button></h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works, thanks! If items are removed from the table how can I remove them from the dropdown as well? The options function is called onclick in the account input.

Comment: @smurf41 Like i mentioned in my answer, on end of every change in list you should call function `options ()` again. So it re-populates the options with new state.

Comment: I did that but it just keeps adding all the elements to the dropdown each time it is clicked. New elements keep being added as duplicates.

Comment: Hard to say, and that is the reason why you should post all relevant code in question. But in your remove function you can add line where it will match removing.innerText with dropdown item.innerText and remove it...

Comment: Here is my full code (only the relevant parts): https://codepen.io/schinken82/pen/bGebOPr

Comment: @smurf41 What exactly do you mean by removing from table? I see no code for that. And I don't see one reason why would you call my function on user input...

Comment: I have a function to remove or add new rows to the table. For example to delete a row I use         `row_id = document.getElementById('row_num').value;
           document.getElementById(row_id).remove();`

Essentially, I always want the content of the drop down to include everything that is currently in the table (adding and deleting elements as necessary). How would I go about making a function that always synchronizes these when called?

Comment: So I added a `document.getElementById('myDropdown').innerHTML = '';` command to the function that closes the drop-down. This way each time the drop-down is opened it'll get the current accounts.

Comment: @smurf41 OK great, but you really did not show me relevant code that I asked for, even in codepen. You talk about remove function that is not there... I can not help much like that. Anyway. Glad that you find the solution yourself.